# Deduction from definition of vector norm

Tags: linear-algebra

A vector norm, $\|x\|$ is a function $\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies

i.) $\|x\| \geq 0$ and $x = 0 \Leftrightarrow \|x\| = 0$$

ii.) $\|\alpha x\| = |\alpha|\|x\|$

iii.) $\|x + y\| \leq \|x\| + \|y\|$

I want to show that

$$\|x - y\| \geq \|x\| - \|y\|$$

Attempted solution:

From the triangle inequality we can deduce that \begin{align*}\|(x+y) + (x - y)\| &\leq \|x+y\| + \|x-y\|\\ &\leq \|x + y\| + \|x - y\|\\ &\leq \|x\| + \|y\| + \|x-y\|
\end{align*}

I know this is a rather trivial exercise but I am sort of stuck on where to go from here. Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: apply the triangle inequality with $(x-y)$ and $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost done: note that
$$
\|(x + y) + (x - y)\| = \|2x\| = 2\|x\|.
$$
Then subtract $\|x\| + \|y\|$ from both sides of your inequality.

Comment: I am not sure how to use what you noted in what I started could you give me some insight on where I go from what you provided?

Comment: @Wolfy, what I wrote down is the left hand side of your inequality. Thus, what you wrote together with what I wrote proves $2\|x\| \leq \|x\| + \|y\| + \|x - y\|$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Yes I got it sorry need some coffee :)

Answer (score 1):

By setting $y=z-x$ in (iii), you can get

$$\|z\| = \|x+(z-x)\| \le \|x\| + \|z-x\| $$

This implies that

$$\|z\| - \|x\|  \le \|z-x\| $$

Answer (score 1):

You can also prove it this way : $\Vert x\Vert=\Vert(x-y)+y\Vert\leqslant\Vert x-y\Vert +\Vert y\Vert$

So $\Vert x\Vert-\Vert y\Vert\leqslant\Vert x-y\Vert$